# facebook share image with clickable URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-sharer

i am tring to share an image from my website to facebook by using the below code :

```
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + MyImageURL,
                        "pop",
                        "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=no");
                    return false;
                });
```

and it is showing the image on facebook, the problem is when some one clicks on the image from facebook site it opens the image like (mydomain.com/image.png) what i need is when user clicks on the image it to open (mydomain.com).

Comment: Then you need to share the link to an HTML document, that has your image set as the thumbnail for sharing, and have that redirect human visitors to your start page.

Comment: I don't want to share the html document. The core of this website is the image so i need to share the image with maximum width.

Comment: That is the only way. If by “maximum width” you mean the full width of the news feed column, as opposed to a little square image with title and description next to it - then go read the sharing documentation on what you have to pay attention to regarding image size/aspect ratio.